# Run .NET app that targets 3.0 on a machine that has only Frameworks 2.0 and 4.0

Tags: c#, .net

Could anyone advise on whether an app that targets .NET 3.0 will work on a users machine that has .NET 2.0 and 4.0 but not 3.0? The installers for 3.0 and 3.5 crash on this particular machine.

Comment: I would focus on why the installers are crashing! Is there any log file produced by the installer that gives a clue as to what is causing the crash?

Comment: Maybe if it just happens to have no references to 3.0 assemblies.  If it references even one 3.0 assembly, I'd say there won't be an easy way to do this-- maybe tracking down each missing 3.0 assembly and putting it in the GAC yourself.

Comment: We can find no logs for the installer that tell us anything. The installer crashes so probably doesn't have an opportunity to log anything. I notice that the Windows Agent and Windows Agent Maintenance services fail to start - could this have anything to do with the installer issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.NET Framework 4.0 is separate and independent from .NET Framework 2.0/3.0/3.5 (all one framework. 2.0 is the base, full, framework. 3.0 and 3.5 are extensions to 2.0.).](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hr/netfxsetup/thread/db61f1a6-8d74-4014-957d-3bdc4d6525e5)

/EDIT

I was curious and quickly tried myself. It actually depends on whether you
build your app against 3.0/3.5 and **really use 3.0/3.5 specific stuff** (for
instance Linq) in the end. If you don't use it, then it will still work of course.

But if you do, then the user will see the Microsoft error reporting dialog.

As it seems there's "no direct targeting .NET 3.0/3.5", because it depends
on the targeted dependencies (project references).

But finally the answer should still be: "No, because you never know!"

Comment: So you are saying that .NET 3.0 will be needed for the application?

Comment: Out of curiosity I've just quickly played with it myself and edited the answer above.

Comment: Thanks - that's kind of what I thought but had been able to un earth anything official that confirmed it. I am using various WCF things so 2.0 is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Is so probable that **.Net4** has all things that your program requires, there is an option to redirect the uses of assemblies (a little tedious but there is) you can modify the configuration file of your application usually named **App.config** in development and **ApplicationName.exe.config** when deployed.

In the section **configuration** try this for all assemblies that should be redirected:

```
<runtime>
<generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
<gcServer enabled="true"/>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 4.0 framework is nominally backward compatible with assemblies compiled for earlier versions (1.1 and later). There is still the possibility that some change in the CLR will break your application. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx for more information.

Moral of the story: Test your 3.5 application on the 4.0 CLR to make sure it works properly.